Redirecting ports in nginx
how can I redirect port 80 of my server to two dockers depending on the url?
that is if the server listens to /main or /login that goes to the docker in 1304
and if just listen to / goes to 1305,
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hello.com.co;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1305;
    }

    location /main {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1304;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1304;
    }
}

I try this:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hello.com.co;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1305;
    }

    location /main {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1304;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1304;
    }
}

but don't works
